# How to send message between users with same token using websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

From the HTML file I am sending message using webSocket.

```
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/{{ token }}");
socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
```

`token` will come from browser URL.

### server.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const qs = require('querystring');
const http = require('http');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 });
const webSockets = {};


wss.on('connection', function (ws, req)
{
    let url = req.url;
    let userToken = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    webSockets[userToken] = ws;
    
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message)
    {
        let messageArray = JSON.parse(message);
        let token = messageArray['token'];
        let toUserWebSocket = webSockets[token];
        toUserWebSocket.send(message);
```

I have opened 3 browsers with following URL

```
`https://url/same_token`
`https://url/same_token`
`https://url/different_token`
```

Messages are being received in all browsers. If message is send from `send_token` I want message to be received only by browser with `same_token`

Comment: Please review the [answer I linked you to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19469286/1144627%5D). You have to bind ws to a token indexed array of clients, then you can send the message to the array of users `webSockets[userToken] = ws`.    `var toUserWebSocket = webSockets[token]`   `toUserWebSocket.send(message)`

Comment: I tried that method already, it is also passing message to everyone

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. What does the client side code look like? Also what does `console.log(userToken)` and `console.log(token)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the issue as described, but was only able to receive the sent message to only one of the connected clients with the same `token`.

The issue with the single connected client is due to `webSockets[userToken] = ws` being referenced, as opposed to using an array of clients `webSockets[userToken] = [];` and `webSockets[userToken].push(ws);`

Also be sure that you do not have a zombie process of `node server.js` running in the background.

```
//...

const clients = {};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
    let id = req.url.substring(req.url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if ('' === id) {
        //connecting id is missing
        ws.terminate();

        return;
    }
    if ('undefined' === typeof clients[id]) {
        clients[id] = [];
    }
    console.log('Connection Received from IP: ' + req.socket.remoteAddress + ' with id ' + id);

    //append websocket client to list of clients
    clients[id].push(ws);

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        if ('' === message) {
            //skip if message is blank
            return;
        }

        try {
            //process message as JSON object as "{"message": "string", "token": "string"}"
            message = JSON.parse(message);
        } catch(e) {
            return;
        }

        if (!message.hasOwnProperty('token') || '' === message.token) {
            //token was not sent or is empty
            return;
        }
        let token = message.token;
        console.log('Message received for token ' + token);

        if ('undefined' !== typeof clients[token] && clients[token]) {
            clients[token].forEach(function(client) {
                if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    //do not send message back to the sending client
                    client.send(message.message + ' ' + token);
                }
            });
        }

        //inform sending client message was sent
        ws.send('Sent: ' + message.message);
    });

    ws.on('close', function() {
        clients[id].forEach(function(client, index) {
            if (client === ws) {
                //remove the client from the pool
                clients[id].splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html code

```
<button type="button" id="sendBtn" class="btn-primary">Send</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/{{ token }}');
    socket.onmessage = function(evt) {
        window.console.log(evt.data);
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#sendBtn').on('click', function() {
            const message = {
                "message": "Hello World",
                "token": "{{ token }}"
            };
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I could check your answer only today. I am not sure if your answer is working or not. I am getting `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
`

Comment: It is probably related to something with the data being sent from the client.. I copy/pasted the code I was using to test with. Would need to know which line the error was on to validate.

Comment: Anyways thank you for your assist. It was difficult time learning websocket(node) for first time